# The seams of my texture appear in my 3D model when I apply it

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, textures

I'm working in a bathroom configurator as you can see in the pictures below.

**The problem are some black edges that appears in the texture of the object. Here are some pictures of the problem:**

*Picture nº1*

[image: Picture nº1]

*Picture nº2*
[image: Picture nº2]

First I've uploaded the bathroom 3d model (in a **.obj** format) and then all the textures applying it to the correct children of the object.

*This is a baked texture I applied to the yellow wall:*
[image: This is a baked texture I applied to the yellow wall]

When the camera approaches the wall or any other object, the black edges disappear. However, when I walk away I can see the edges again.

Actually, I think it's the edges of the mesh of my object instead of the texture seams.

Is there any possible solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if we had access to the model but it looks like it might be seams between disconnected triangles. If possible you can try adjusting the geometry so those triangles share an edge. If you can't do that (because objects are being placed next to each other) then you could try making the objects overlap just a little bit.

Comment: Are you performing any filtering to your texture? If you're changing the `texture.minFilter` property from the default value, it could be that there is no mipmapping taking place, which could explain why the effect happens when you walk away from the walls, but not when you're up close.